# Connecting Leap And QT Togther

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, leap-motion

after long long search over the internet i did not found any reason able solution to my problem which is that:

i have an application that record the user finger  movement on demand, (when the user pressing r its start to record when the user press the s its stop the record,

till now i the application was on the console so it worked perfectly with leap motion,
now we have decided to move the application to GUI based application, and we have chosen QT platform, we integrated the GUI with our solution , we have placed two push buttons to replace the key pressing , and connected the events.
the real problem started when we wanted to see what was captured by the onFrame call back of the leap listener and we have noticed ever since the Main GUI of the QT is preformed the callbacks of the leap are some how blocked or just dont get cpu time(i dont know the real issue) , we tried several solutions like using a wrapper class that inherit from QObject and 
start a thread from there but it doesnt seem to effect anything.

here is the main.cpp

```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    LeapClass::QLeapLis * smp = LeapClass::QLeapLis::get_instance();

    QThread * th =  smp->thread();
    //smp->moveToThread(th);
    th->start(QThread::HighPriority);


    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

here the QLeapLis is the Wrapper class, that has a run method that start the device,
but still noting happens, i am very close to give up on QT.

if someone knows how to connect those two we will be grateful

Many Thanks.

Comment: As always: show the entire code for `QLeapLis`.

Comment: The entire thread thing you have there is pointless: the `smp` object is already in its thread (the GUI thread), and that thread is already started (`main` runs in it!). So trying to start an already running thread, or moving an object to a thread it's already in - what's the point?

Comment: Leap's `Controller` object is already multithreaded, so you don't need to be doing anything special, really, apart from realizing that the `Listener` class that you may have is invoked in another thread and can *only* use the Qt APIs that are thread safe. It is supposed only to be posting events and/or sending signals, since both of those are thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below demonstrates how you should use the `Listener` API correctly with Qt.

This code does *not* require to be run through `moc`. I've also checked that it builds and runs with Leap SDK.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include "leap.h"

class MyListener : public QObject, public Leap::Listener {
public:
   virtual void onFrame(const Leap::Controller & ctl) {
      Leap::Frame f = ctl.frame();
      // This is a hack so that we avoid having to declare a signal and
      // use moc generated code.
      setObjectName(QString::number(f.id()));
      // emits objectNameChanged(QString)
   }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   MyListener listener;
   Leap::Controller controller;
   controller.addListener(listener);

   QLabel frameLabel;
   frameLabel.setMinimumSize(200, 50);
   frameLabel.show();
   frameLabel.connect(&listener, SIGNAL(objectNameChanged(QString)),
                      SLOT(setText(QString)));

   int rc = a.exec();
   controller.removeListener(listener);
   return rc;
}
```

Comment: as you mentioned in the comments above, the leap creates the thread it self and by trying to wrap it with QThread it Kills it, i found a suitable solution for now , that i am Calling LeapClass::SimpleListener * listener; from the main.cpp so its works for now. that signal i will transfer throw the network with QTcp socket ot something

 Leap::Controller controller;
 controller.addListener(*listener->get_instance());

Comment: @whIsrael I'm showing you *exactly what to do*, just drop my dummy Leap implementation. It should work and be plug-and-play. Why would you want to "wrap" Leap::Controller's own threads? It's unnecessary.

Comment: i also get error from your main.. about the listener.. :(

Comment: "i also get error from your main.. about the listener" I can't read your mind. What error, pray tell?

Comment: i am Amazed it does work perfectly!! , no i can emit signal throw the onFrame call back right?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the issue by not using the Leap callbacks. You can call Controller::frame() using an animation loop or other convenient looping mechanism to get the latest frame of data. (Each Frame object has an ID so you can tell if you have already processed a frame).

For example, in some environments (Processing, the browser animation loop, Unity, Cinder, etc) there is already an update loop that is called at the application's drawing frame rate. Processing frame data more frequently than this can also be a waste of time. Even if your application isn't already multithreaded, you will have to start dealing with some of the complications that can come with multithreading when you use the LM callback implementation.

According to Kuba Ober, QT widgets don't have an animation or draw loop, so his answer showing the correct way to use the Listener callbacks is the right approach here.

Comment: This is cargo cult programming kind of an answer. Almost every sentence in it is wrong, in spite of appearing coherent. Callbacks are there for a reason, you're supposed to use them. No, calling `frame()` on a timer is not the right way to do it, and an unnecessary complication. No, you don't have to sleep in one thread to give another thread "time" to execute (threads would be pointless if it were so).

Comment: Huh? If your application already has a looping mechanism, then adding multithreading through the callbacks is often an unnecessary complication.

Comment: The multithreading isn't done "through" the callbacks. The callbacks are simply a way for Leap's internal thread to communicate with your code. It's equivalent to sending signals, although a bit more clumsy. The main benefit is that you're notified of things immediately, and the latency is as minimal as possible. The "looping mechanism" is meant ideally to be mostly blocking, waiting for a kernel event. The more you poll, the more energy you waste, and the worse your application feels to the user.

Comment: It depends. In some environments (Processing, the browser animation loop, Unity, Cinder, etc) there is already an update loop that is called at the application's drawing frame rate. Processing frame data more frequently than this can also be a waste of time. If your application isn't already multithreaded, then you are **adding** multithreading when you use the LM callback implementation.

Comment: Edited answer based on Kuba Ober's feedback