# updating qt gui when running a method

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface, worker

i know how to use qt threads, but it is possible to use a thread to update gui without subclassing qthread or qobject?
for example:

```
class Foo {
    public void heavyWork();
}

Foo::heavyWork() {
    doSomething();
}
```

and using a thread (just an option)

```
void ThreadSubClass::run() {
    myFoo.heavyWork();
    updateGui(); //i know, heavyWork will run before updateGui()
}
```

i don't want to subclass qobject or qthread to implement my "foo" class because this class could be (or should be) use independently of gui library (or even in console), i'm using Qt, but i plan to try anything else

Comment: Note that Qt is not a gui library, it is an application development framework. That's a rather important difference. Namely, Qt applications, even using the gui and widgets modules, can run headlessly - without using any screens, or even without any human interaction at all. Qt's core and network modules are applicable to a lot of non-gui, server-style development. Heck, many common Unix utilities look downright trivial when reimplemented in Qt, even though their C implementations are monstrous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I presume that `Foo`'s methods execute in a worker thread, and you wish to offer a mechanism to pass some data from `Foo` to a GUI thread.

The typical way of doing it is to provide a mechanism of executing a callback within `Foo`'s thread - the callback's implementation then is specific to the particular GUI toolkit that's in use.

The callback can be a simple function pointer, or an interface (observer pattern). For example:

```
class FooObserver {
  friend class Foo;
protected:
  virtual void update(Foo *) = 0;
};

class Foo {
  int m_data;
  std::list<std::shared_ptr<FooObserver>> m_observers;
public:
  void heavyWork();
  int data() const;
  void addObserver(std::shared_ptr<FooObserver> observer);
}

void Foo::addObserver(std::shared_ptr<FooObserver> observer)
{
  m_observers.push_back(observer);
}

void Foo::heavyWork()
{
  ...
  for (auto observer: m_observers) observer->update(this);
}
```

Then, for Qt, you could have:

```
class QtFooObserver : public FooObserver {
  Q_OBJECT
  void update(Foo * foo) override { emit newData(foo->data()); }
public:
  QtFooObserver() {}
  Q_SIGNAL void newData(int);
};
```

This is perfectly thread-safe, since the determination of signal's thread happens upon signal emission. The `QtFooObserver` object can reside in any thread, including a thread different from `Foo`'s thread. Thus if `Foo` is in thread A, and a slot connected to `QtFooObserver` is on an object in thread B, Qt will automatically use a thread-safe cross-thread signal delivery method.

For more inspiration, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22641965/1329652) and the [Leap Motion C++ SDK](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/cpp/api/Leap.Listener.html).